# using "grep" to print the lines where the same sequence of 4 or more consecutive characters comes in at least 3 times

Tags: grep

I'm trying to find the lines where the same sequence of 4 or more consecutive characters comes in at least 3 times, using the `grep` command

```
 grep '^.*\(....\)*\1*\1*' file.name
```

for ex

```
  ADShDS DFDFG HGFDFDFD DFDFD
  ASFG VVFGTTTE DSrFD GFFDSD C
  KKKYX KKKYXFF KaKFVBB KKKYXY
```

expected output

```
  ADShDS DFDFG HGFDFDFD DFDFD
  KKKYX KKKYXFF KaKFVBB KKKYXY
```

but there is something wrong !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
grep '\(....\).*\1.*\1' file
```

or

```
grep -E '(....).*\1.*\1' file
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: i meant where the same sequence of 4 or more consecutive characters ( only big letters  ) comes in at least 3 times

Comment: grep '\([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\).*\1.*\1' , this work